# CentOS 6 ssh is not prompting for the verification code?

Tags: ssh, centos6, pam, freeradius

I have installed the pam radius rpm package, and successfully configured /etc/pam.d/sshd, /etc/ssh/sshd_config, & /etc/pam_radius.conf. I know it is working, as i am getting a push notification to my handheld device after i enter my password. When I approve the push notification i am able to log in. My concern is, why am i not being prompted to enter the Verification Code if i don't respond via the out of band notification. Whats even more odd is, on our debian based systems (Ubuntu), it works as expected. Seems only redhat based systems have the issue.

**Current Behavior:**
I am only able to respond out of band to confirm the 2FA authentication. If I fail to respond I am then prompted for the password again, instead of the Verification Code.

[CentOS 6 Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBC1K.png)

**Expected Behavior:**
If i fail to respond to the out of band notification (ie phone in airplane mode) ssh should failover and prompt for a "Verification code"

[Ubuntu Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifu0U.png)

Thanks in advance.

#### /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

#### /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       sufficient   pam_radius_auth.so
```

#### Logfile /var/log/secure

```
Jan 12 17:26:51 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name username
Jan 12 17:26:54 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: Sending RADIUS request code 1
Jan 12 17:26:54 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: DEBUG: getservbyname(radius, udp) returned 411494816.
Jan 12 17:27:09 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: RADIUS server 10.1.69.126 failed to respond
Jan 12 17:27:09 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: All RADIUS servers failed to respond.
Jan 12 17:27:09 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_radius_auth: authentication failed
Jan 12 17:27:09 mddirector unix_chkpwd[9303]: password check failed for user (username)
Jan 12 17:27:09 mddirector sshd[9242]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=username
Jan 12 17:27:12 mddirector sshd[9240]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for username from ::1
Jan 12 17:27:12 mddirector sshd[9304]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name username
```

Comment: Is this Duo Security you're working with?

Comment: No it is not. It is toopher based. Again, whats odd is this works as it should on our debian boxes.

Comment: This seems very much like a toopher problem. Have you talked with their support?

Comment: I have, and because there is no issue on the Debian side, they say it isn't their problem.

Comment: did you check selinux? ;)

Comment: Yes, selinux is disabled

Comment: What do you see in the server logs?

Comment: Updated the post with the logging data

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help :)

I had to increase the timeout in the pam_radius.conf changed it from 15 to 30.